# Parse JSON String with regular expression in Python

Tags: python, json, regex

I have a JSON string

```
json_str = '''
{"conversation_id": "314123790001", "first_agent_id": 85860001, "customer_id": 62483180001, "first_utterance_ts": "2020-08-18T15:37:04.826000+00:00", "first_utterance_text": "Wan indicator light", "first_intent_code": "TSMODEM", "first_intent_code_alt": "TSBOX", "final_intent_code": "TSWIFI", "intent_path": "TSMODEM,TSWIFI", "disambig_count": 0, "ftd_visit": true, "faq_id": null, "final_action_destination": null, "is_first_intent_correct": null, "issue_id": "314123790001", "first_rep_id": 85860001, "company_name": "spectrum-cable"}
'''
```

I used this regular expression command;

```
_key = "intent_path"
values = re.findall(r'\"{}\"\s?:\s?\"?([^\,\"]+)\"?'.format(_key), json_str)
```

However, I got a result "TSMODEM". My expected result is "TSMODEM,TSWIFI"

I want to get only a value for a key("intent_path"). I want to get the value with regular expression. Can you help me?

Comment: Why regex (is a bad choice for structured data)? Do you want to parse all fields or just extract a single value?

Comment: "with regular expression, but not a json python library" - can you please elaborate the reason? Also, have you already tried anything yourself?

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to use a JSON library ? This is **litteraly** their only purpose.

Comment: because I often get a broken JSON string, so I want to use regular expression.

Comment: If you get a broken JSON often the regex could also be broken. Fix whatever is giving you the JSON or if its a third party report the bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've came up with this regex, which might work in most cases but not all. Since you said you might have broken regex, it's hard to know what the output will look like. Anyways, this might work fine for your needs.

```py
r'"intent_path":(?: ?)"([\w\s,]+)"'
```

You can test more cases [here](https://regex101.com/r/BmMaKN/6)

Comment: @Adirio Oh, it does. Nice than. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex:

```
intent_path":\s*"((?:(?!(?<!\\)").)*)"
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WviYUX/1/)

1. `"intent_path":\s*"` Matches "intent_path": followed by 0 or more white space characters followed by a ".
2. `((?:(?!(?<!\\)").)*)` Matches 0 or more characters as long as it is not a " character that is not preceded by a backslash. These characters are accumulated in capture group 1.
3. `"` Matches a " character

The code:

```
import re

json_str = '''
{"conversation_id": "314123790001", "first_agent_id": 85860001, "customer_id": 62483180001, "first_utterance_ts": "2020-08-18T15:37:04.826000+00:00", "first_utterance_text": "Wan indicator light", "first_intent_code": "TSMODEM", "first_intent_code_alt": "TSBOX", "final_intent_code": "TSWIFI", "intent_path": "TSMODEM,TSWIFI", "disambig_count": 0, "ftd_visit": true, "faq_id": null, "final_action_destination": null, "is_first_intent_correct": null, "issue_id": "314123790001", "first_rep_id": 85860001, "company_name": "spectrum-cable"}
'''

_key = "intent_path"
m = re.search(fr'"{re.escape(_key)}":\s*"((?:(?!(?<!\\)").)*)"', json_str)
if m:
    print(m[1])
```

Prints:

```
TSMODEM,TSWIFI
```